# How do you check if an MKAnnotation is available within a MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I've noticed that if I use MKMapView's `selectAnnotation:animated:`, that it will scroll my map off screen if the MKAnnotation is not displayed in the current MKCoordinateRegion that my map is displaying.

Is there a trivial way to check if an annotation is currently on screen within the specified MKCoordinateRegion? I'd like to be able to select an annotation that's only on screen and not something offscreen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `annotationsInMapRect:` method in the [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) class. It returns a `NSSet` of all annotation objects that are visible in the given map rect. Use the `containsObject:` method of `NSSet` to test if the annotation is present in that set of visible annotations.

```
MKMapRect visibleMapRect = aMapView.visibleMapRect;
NSSet *visibleAnnotations = [aMapView annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect];
BOOL annotationIsVisible = [visibleAnnotations containsObject:someAnnotation];
```

Also `visibleMapRect` is same as the region but just a different form of representation. Take from the docs,

> `visibleMapRect`
>
> The area currently displayed by the map view.
>
> `@property(nonatomic) MKMapRect visibleMapRect`
>
> This property represents the same basic information as the region property but specified as a map rectangle instead of a region.

Comment: Does this account for custom annotationviews that are larger than the standard MKAnnotationView? What I mean is that it may be visible, but it may be somewhat offscreen.

Comment: Wheres the Plus 100 button! Thanks.

Comment: Does this account for map rotation? Take a look at the image in this [article](https://medium.com/@dmytrobabych/getting-actual-rotation-and-zoom-level-for-mapkit-mkmapview-e7f03f430aa9) to see how the region is represented in relation to the screen when the map is rotated.

Comment: @JoshBernfeld did you find a solution for map rotation?