# MKAnnotation not visible *until* user drags map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm building an app where annotations mark points of interest that the user drives by. The map tracks the user's location and scrolls along, but annotations that should come into view on the map don't appear until the user drags the map with her finger.

Adding and removing annotations works fine so I'm not sure what code to show.

Has anyone seen similar behavior?

**Edit:**

This affects only some annotations - some appear, some don't. No apparent pattern.

As suggested, I've changed the code so that I add and remove annotations only on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotationsToAdd];
});
```

But the problem persists. Darn...

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Are you adding the annotations on the main thread?  If not, try dispatching them to the main thread using dispatch_async

Comment: Most likely it's related to adding annotations from a background thread as @aeskreis says.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862914/loading-annotations-from-url-using-background-thread-pins-doesnt-show-before-m, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170445/mkmapview-not-refreshing-annotations, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995245/iphone-mapview-interrupted, etc.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've found a couple places where I might have been adding annotations on a background thread. I'll test my changes tomorrow morning and report back here. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 3):

For me I just had to call addAnnotations on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
    });
```

And it works fine

Answer (score 2):

when you add an annotation call all the following methods on that annotation for it to show.

```
[_mapView addAnnotation:theAnnotation];
[_mapView deselectAnnotation:theAnnotation animated:NO];
[_mapView selectAnnotation:theAnnotation animated:NO];
```

For some of the apps I have worked on, unless you deselect and select the annotation, it wouldn't show it on the map (even if you just add it). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - adding and removing annotations works as expected. It's only when the map scrolls (automatically, by tracking the user location) so that the annotation should become visible that it doesn't appear.

Dragging or zooming the map manually somehow refreshes or reloads the annotations, making them visible again.

Comment: so, your map is continuously animating keeping the user's current location in the center?

Comment: Yep, like this:

`[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];`

Comment: This does work but when map region changes my callout is displayed which isn't very nice so that's what I did which work fine: `[_mapView selectAnnotation:theAnnotation animated:NO];
[_mapView deselectAnnotation:theAnnotation animated:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing any of your code. That being said, if you haven't already, try checking to see if any of the annotations are within the current visible map area in mapView:didUpdateUserLocation and, if they are, refresh your map view (see the answer to [How do you check if an MKAnnotation is available within a  MKCoordinateRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675759/3769138) for more on checking annotations against the visible map rect).